# How to authenticate to a Firebase database using Android Things?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-things

I am starting to experiment with Android Things and I am trying to connect my app to a Firebase Realtime Database in a secure way.

The problem is that Firebase Authentication [is not available](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html#google-services) in Things because it requires user interaction.

I don't want to leave my data public, so is there a way to authenticate to a Firebase Database using something like an API key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android Things, you can still do anonymous auth and email/password auth.  With email/password, you can create a special account for your Thing in the console, and use those credentials to log in.  The downside is that you're either baking the password into the Thing, or finding a way to get a hold of them that's somehow more secure.

Comment: Thanks Doug! The issue I was having is that I had the wrong version of the Firebase libraries in my app. Android Things have Google Play services v11.0.4 (https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html), so I had to use this same version for Firebase as well.

Comment: Ah, yes, I discovered that myself lately.  The version of Play is baked into the thing and doesn't currently update itself like regular android devices.

Comment: @DougStevenson  Bringing key pair authentication to firebase (as done for Cloud IoT) would be a big win. Until then, Firebase seems incomplete for production use with Things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal android app and communicate with your things app using [Nearby2.0](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) API of google. So now like this you can pass email id and password as payload in a decodable encrypted form to your things app from the normal android app. So no need to use anonymous auth at all. Once you passed the credentials save it in sharedpref in things app and reuse as needed.

Hope this helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In Android Things, Firebase Authentication is supported. See [this](https://plus.google.com/111222236483466409090/posts/RDLDHNjMLtn) link for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link!