# How to communicate with Firebase database form Android Things using a service account

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin, android-things

I have an Android client and an Android Things server application sharing a Firebase database. How can I communicate from the Android Things application with the Firebase database using a service account? Following the instructions below results in a Gradle error.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Gradle error

`Error:(56, 0) Version: 5.8.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several things going wrong here.

First, you don't need a service account to deal with Firebase services from within an Android Things app.  You deal with Firebase just like you would a normal Android app as a client of the Firebase service.  There is literally almost no difference in how you interface with Firebase from this perspective.

Second, don't use firebase-admin in an Android app.  That's for server-side code.  Use the normal Firebase client SDKs for Android.

Also bear in mind that Android Things Developer Preview 0.6.1 has Play Services 11.6.x on it, and it doesn't self-update like normal Android devices.  This means you have to use the 11.6.0 Firebase and Play SDKs in your Thing app.  If you try to use newer versions, the client will fail because the client SDK versions aren't matched by an equal or better Play Services APK on the device.

Comment: How do you handle authentication in this scenario? As the Android Things app is non-interactive, I cannot use user credentials. The Android Things application is a server side application in this case.

Comment: It would be a disaster if you bundled admin credentials into your app that got distributed to end users.  You would be hacked in the worst possible way.  Instead, you can share a user auth token between a companion app and your thing.  This is a complicated topic, and well outside the scope of your original question.

Comment: Could you ask another question, tag it with "firebase" at the very least, and that could then be detailed with a properly formatted response?

Comment: This answer seems to be good enough for my use case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044932/how-to-authenticate-to-a-firebase-database-using-android-things

Comment: If that meets your needs!  Bear in mind that anonymous auth may not be the best possible solution.  Enabling anonymous auth in your project could lead to other problems, especially if you need to lock down specific parts of your data to specific users.  But it would get you started right away.